# dropping the lowest values from a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a python program that drops 25% of the lowest values from a list and (return the original unsorted list). For example;

```
Input : [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8] 
Output : [5,6,72,4,9,11,8]
```

I tried to do:

```
l = [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8]

def drop(k):
     while len(l)!=0 and k > 0:
        k = k - 1
        l.sort(reverse = True)
        l.pop()
 return l

k = math.ceil(len(l) * 0.25)
drop (k)
```

it returns [72, 11, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4] but is there a way to do it without sorting?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require to reverse sort and find the smallest element. Use `min` on list `l` which returns the smallest value from `l` and remove using `l.remove` conveniently.

```
import math
l = [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8]

def drop(k):
     while len(l)!=0 and k > 0:
        k = k - 1
        l.remove(min(l))
     return l

k = math.ceil(len(l) * 0.25)
print(drop (k))
# [5, 6, 72, 4, 9, 11, 8]
```

Comment: Repeatedly calling `remove` and `min` on the same list is horribly slow. This solution is completely unsuitable for longer lists.

Comment: This looks pretty O(n^2) to me. Also, removing random elements one by one is very inefficieint.

Comment: In fact, I used pop in the first place because it is O(1). May I have another suggestion, please?

Comment: @Aran-Fey All I did was to tell OP where he went wrong by explaining through his code rather than building something new. OP needs to understand his code and his errors. None of the other answers explain that.

Comment: @PaulPanzer please see my recent comment.

Comment: See, the thing is, sorting is actually _better_ than calling `min` on the same list a thousand times. (If the sort is moved out of the loop, that is.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Feels like sorting is better but not inside the loop anyway. Thanks for pointing that out. But I don't think this would raise much complications because the list appears smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `heapq` and keep popping elements until 25% of the container has been removed. Then, filter the contents of the original list

```
import heapq, copy
s = [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8] 
new_s = copy.deepcopy(s)
heapq.heapify(s)
count = 0
last_items = set()
while count/float(len(new_s)) <= 0.25:
  last_items.add(heapq.heappop(s))
  count += 1

final_s = [i for i in new_s if i not in last_items]
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 72, 4, 9, 11, 8]
```

Comment: They want the original order maintained.

Comment: Sure. You really ought to make `last_items` a set though.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is **this is very slow especially for longer lists!**:

```
quart_len = int(0.25*len(l))
for i in range(quart_len):
     l.remove(min(l))
```

**A much faster way of doing this:**

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil

l = [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8]
sorted_values = np.array(l).argsort()
l_new = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i in sorted_values[int(ceil(len(l)/4.)):]]
```

Another approach:

```
l = np.array(l)
l = list(l[l > sorted(l)[len(l)/4]])
```

Comment: I can't even begin to describe how horribly slow this solution is.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I know, but speed requirements were never specified and it seems a short list.

Comment: People copy/paste code from StackOverflow on a daily basis - if your code is horribly slow in a lot of real-world scenarios, I think your answer should have a disclaimer about that, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

There are O(n) solutions to [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). One of those, introselect, is implemented in numpy in the `partition` and `argpartition` functions:

```
>>> data = [1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8] 
>>> 
>>> k = int(round(len(data) / 4))
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dnp = np.array(data)
>>> drop_them = np.argpartition(dnp, k)[:k]
>>> keep_them = np.ones(dnp.shape, dtype=bool)
>>> keep_them[drop_them] = False
>>> result = dnp[keep_them].tolist()
>>> 
>>> result
[5, 6, 72, 4, 9, 11, 3, 8]
```

Note that this method keeps one of the `3`s and drops the other one in order to get the split at exactly `k` elements.

If instead you want to treat all `3`s the same, you could do

```
>>> boundary = np.argpartition(dnp, k)[k]
>>> result = dnp[dnp > dnp[boundary]]
>>> 
>>> result
array([ 5,  6, 72,  4,  9, 11,  8])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=[1,5,6,72,3,4,9,11,3,8]
l2=sorted(l1)
ln=round(len(l1)*0.25)
[i for i in l1 if i not in l2[ln+1:]]
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 72, 4, 9, 11, 8]
```

Comment: You could achieve a significant speedup by turning `l2` into a set, or at least negating the `if i in l2[ln+1:]` to `if i not in l2[:ln+1]`.

Comment: we are still sorting here.